# Angular drag and drop: Items should not remove from container after drag and dropped

Tags: angular-material, angulardraganddroplists

I am using **Angular drag and drop CDK**:

I am able to drag and drop items from one container to another and vice versa. Now, I am trying to not to **remove** a dropped item from a container, but it should be ***dropped*** into another container.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to **drag** an item ***"Go home"*** from ***'To do'*** container to ***'Done'*** container.

I want to ***keep*** an item after dropped.

**Example:** https://stackblitz.com/angular/bypeyxpbvxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Any help, please...

Comment: I don't think is possible trough angulat-material. You should first make a copy of the element you want to move, and then move the copy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite easy. Just use copyArrayItem instead of transferArrayItem

```
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  copyArrayItem,
  moveItemInArray
} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      copyArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while keeping the original in its place while dragging the preview around? Like currently, you grab it, it gets temporarily removed from the original list, then you drop it, and it gets added to both lists. Is there a way to prevent it being temporarily removed?

Comment: @user973223 looking for the same solution, any updates?

Comment: Looking for a resolution for above comment. Any update?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the item removed while copying, use the cdkDragStarted like this in your HTML:

```
(cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event, dataList, index)"
```

and the method:

```
dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart, dataList, index) {
 if (this.dropMode  === 'copy') {
   dataList.splice(index, 0, event.source.data);
 }
}

onDropped(event) {
  event.previousContainer.dataList.splice(event.previousIndex,1);

  // your code to copy the item...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `copyArrayItem` instead of `transferArrayItem`.
Change:

```
transferArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    toIndex
);
```

to

```
copyArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    toIndex
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work by using cdkDragStarted and cdkDragDropped

HTML:

```
 <mat-row
        cdkDrag
        cdkDragHandle
        (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
        (cdkDragDropped)="dragStopped($event)"
    >
    </mat-row>
```

TS:

```
dragStarted(event: any) {
this.dataSource.data.splice(
  this.dataSource.data.findIndex(
    (d: TableRow) => d.ID === event.source.data[0].ID
  ) + 1,
  0,
  event.source.data[0]
);
this.table?.renderRows();
}

dragStopped(event: any) {
this.dataSource.data.splice(
  this.dataSource.data.findIndex(
    (d: TableRow) => d.ID === event.item.data[0].ID
  ),
  1
);
this.table?.renderRows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible with angular-material. Here is a possible solution

```
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}} <span (click)="copyMe(item)">Copy</span> </div>
```

```
 copyMe(item: any) {
    console.log(item)
    const newItem = item
    this.todo.push(newItem)
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xlkxgkneavr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I am looking for a better way. I do not want to copy items. I simply drag and drop without removing items from a container **"To do"**.